# Embedded Scripting language as customization point for (Strawberry) Perl and C#

Tags: c#, strawberry-perl

I am investigating the options of creating customization logic in a Client/Server application. I envision that the customer will be writing the logic in scripting language, stored in configuration files.

The client side is written in C# (NET 3.5) and server side is Perl (Strawberry Perl on Windows). I expect the script can be executed on both side, on both platform.

**The question is - I have yet be able to pick a scripting language/engine that could be embedded in both.**

Embedding X in C# is a easy part - looks like there are options/library everywhere. The Strawberry Perl part is hard. I was looking at Lua and Javascript. There isn't seems an good module for calling Lua from Perl, not to mention I have not started investigate how to get things compile. I am also looking at JavaScript::V8, although I could get the V8 compiled in Windows, but JavaScript::V8 module refuse to compile.

I am open to any scripting language (Lua, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, Perl...whatever), I bet someone here might have walked this through already and could shine some hints?

My current fallback plans is using Javascript [Module JE (Pure Perl Javascript engine), V8 on C#] but I am conservative about its performance (Perl part). I hope there is some better options.